# Would these two if statements mean the same thing?

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
if (people[i]->alive() == false)

if (!(*people[i]).alive())
```

Would the second line of code work identical to the first one? If not, why is the second one different?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: They are identical (assuming normal pointers and not objects with overloaded dereference operators).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're the same, assuming there aren't unusual operator overloads in effect. I'd recommend:

```
if (!people[i]->alive())
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

```
using people_type = std::decay_t<decltype(people[i])>;
```

and no overloads for

- `people_type::operator->() /* cv/ref qualifier*/`
- `people_type::operator*() /* cv/ref qualifier*/`

then `people[i]->alive()` and `(*people[i]).alive()` are equivalent.

Now, assuming that

```
using alive_type = std::decay_t<decltype(people[i]->alive())>;
```

and no overloads for

- `alive_type::operator!() /* cv/ref qualifier*/`
- `alive_type::operator==(bool /*or compatible*/ ) /* cv/ref qualifier*/`
- `operator==(/* cv/ref qualifier*/ alive_type, bool /*or compatible*/)`

then `people[i]->alive() == false` and `!(*people[i]).alive()` are compatible.

If one of these overload exists, the equivalence depends of the implementation, but it would be bad style to make these 2 codes different as user expects that there are compatible when no overload.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!people[i]->alive())
```

This will work since the `alive()` function return a `boolean` value,and the if will execute whenever the return is a  `false`.

Comment: Actually that will give you a compilation error. It also doesn't answer the question of if the two forms are identical.

Comment: `#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class test
{
 int a;
public: test()
  {
  }
  bool func()
  {
   return false;
  } 
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{  
  test *cd[5];
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i< 5; ++i)
  {
  cd[i] = new test; 
  if(!cd[i]->func())
   cout << "Working";
  }

 _getch();
 return 0;
}` Here is sample code, compile it and let me know if any error, And explain what is the compile error you have got ?

Comment: I was referring to the stray `)` which you noticed and fixed.

Comment: Sorry for that, Thanks for the suggestion